# Is there a better way to find if an iterator has reached its last value?

Tags: javascript, iterator

I can do this:

```
let iter = mySet.values();
var val = iter.next();
var next = iter.next();
while(val.value){
  if(!next.done){
    // do something that I want to do to the last element
  }
  val = next;
  next  = iter.next();
}
```

but the 'next' variable seems clumsy.  Is there a better way?

When I inspect the mySet object, I see a key of [[Entries]] with an array of values, but how would I access that?

Comment: You can use a for..of loop if you do not need to know the index

Comment: Does javascript offer the `iterator.hasNext()` method?  Never used it in javascript, but that method is offered in other languages.

Comment: `mySet.value();` Is that a Set? If so, do you mean `.values()`?

Comment: We'd have to look at what exactly you're trying to do in order to determine if there's a better way. Generally looping or using a spread operator is best when using `Set` and, oftentimes, `Set` is actually unnecessary. Furthermore it adds a performance hit to the Browser whenever it's used in lieu of something like, say, Array. It really depends on usecase, but honestly a *great*, *great*, majority of the time, writing out iterator iterations(*yeah, I said it*) painstakingly is hardly ever reasonable.

Comment: @zfrisch why is a Set a performance hit? Set.has() is more performant than Array.find or Array.some or indexOf

Comment: @charlietfl I would have to look through past posts for the tests I performed but the construction and utilization of the has method is more intensive than building an Array and using `Array.includes` - and in this case where the user is specifically trying to grab the last element in a Set to perform something, an Array is quicker and easier to utilize. The only time it isn't is most likely due to a large dataset. Iterators have benefits, but if you're only using Set for non-dups, an Array is faster and I believe that's because it's not tied into perpetual stop-and-go type operations.

Comment: It's an estimation because I haven't performed this specific test, but looping through iterators is an abstraction of a more intensive loop under the hood, whereas a loop over an Array is exactly what it appears to be.

Comment: @zfrisch just did a quick search and found a valid jsperf https://jsperf.com/array-indexof-vs-set-has

Comment: @charlietfl you may very well be right, but I'll have to take a look in a bit :) . I'm on mobile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `while(!next.done)` and you only want to use `next()` once per iteration.

To figure out if it is the last value, store value in variable then reassign `next` and then check `done` before processing the value

```js
function* myGen(arr) {
  let i = -1;
  while (++i < arr.length) {
    yield arr[i] * 2;
  }
}

const it = myGen([1, 2, 3]);

let next = it.next();

while (!next.done) {
  const val = next.value;
  next = it.next();
  console.log('value:', val, ' is last = ', next.done);
}

console.log('done:', next.done)
```

Comment: the point of the question was to be able to know when we are looking at the last element, and treat it differently.

Comment: ok...simple fix... check `next.done` inside the loop also after new assignment and store value inside loop in variable first. Then you can work with value *after* checking done and before while loop closes

Comment: that saves 1 line from my approach; the initial `var val = iter.next();` .  Thanks for the improvement.  But you are saying, fundamentally I still need the 2 variables to see when I'm at the last element?

Comment: Seems you were calling next too many times though. And yes....don't see a way around one variable for value and one for the next object

Comment: in practice, it is the same number of times as you.

Comment: Referring to `var val = iter.next();var next = iter.next();` called back to back

Answer (score 1):

## From Mozilla's [Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators):

"...next() method which returns an object with two properties: value, the next value in the sequence; and **done, which is true if the last value in the sequence has already been consumed.**"

Nothing is wrong with your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about others, but I see the last `return` value from the generator is missing when I use [accepted solution by @charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55660647/340290) as the value after last `.next()` is ignored.

So, I used below simple `do...while` loop. Again just one call to `.next()`

```js
function* numberGen() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
  yield 4;
  yield 5;
  return 6;
}
console.clear();

const numbers = numberGen();

let nextNumber;
do {
  nextNumber = numbers.next();
  const val = nextNumber.value;
  console.log('value:', val, ' is last = ', nextNumber.done);
} while (!nextNumber.done);


console.log('done:', nextNumber.done);
```

Comment: Thank you.  So this is great if I am defining the iterable, and can return the last value.